Trouble fetching data in a client component (Next.js)
I want to fetch data from an external API in a client component. However, console.log outputs nothing (although it correctly outputs that the type is string).
The API in question is a working endpoint, and I had no problems fetching data in a server component.
The code
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Get() {
    const [averageSalary, setAverageSalary] = useState(null);

    async function getAverageSalary() {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/`, {
            mode: "no-cors",
        });
        const result = await response.text();

        console.log(typeof(result)); // => string
        console.log(result); // => 

        setAverageSalary(result);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getAverageSalary();
    },[]);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Average salary: {averageSalary}</h1>
        </>
    );
}


Have you tried using mode: "cors" and enabling cors on your backend/API?

yup, glad to help!
